# Number ways of arranging dots and lines with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I have this problem where I need to calculate the following:

For x dots and y lines, how many arrangements are possible such that no more than n dots are together?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

First put all the lines, like this | | | | |

Then, out of y lines,$y+1$ gaps will be created (including end spaces). Maximum number of dots in each gap is $n$.
Now, let the number of dots in $i$th gap is $x_i$.
Required number of ways is the number of non-negative solutions of the equation
$$x_1+x_2+...+x_{y+1}=x$$
Where $x_i\leq n \forall i$, now you can easily do it by finding the coefficient of $m^x$ in the expansion of $(1+m+m^2+...+m^n)^{y+1}$.

Hope it is helpful:)

Comment: In the case where x = 4, n = 5 and y = 1, the restriction of n basically doesn't come into effect, so we can just calculate the possibilities the normal way: 

Arrangements = 6C1 = 6.

Using your method, I would get 10C4 = 210, which is not the same. Is there something more which we need to consider with your method?

Comment: This method treats different “spots” in the same gap as distinct. But they should not be; you’re significantly overcounting.

Comment: Ok, I have edited it to correct.